# Using MSBuild to publish webservices

Tags: .net, web-services, msbuild

How do I publish a Web Service to a server with MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en). It is basically an msbuild file that makes it wasy to perform your deployment steps. I use it in combination with the [MSBuild community tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) which has msbuild tasks for zipping files, assigning your assembly version number from your subversion repository and other commonly needed actions.

Also, the [MSDeploy](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/01/22/welcome-to-the-web-deployment-team-blog.aspx) tool from microsoft supports command line deployment and configuration of IIS, etc, and would be easy to plug into the deployment project.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be the same way to publish an ASP.NET application?